# Evaluate $\Re[\cos(1+i)]$

Tags: complex-numbers

Evaluate $\Re[\cos(1+i)]$.
The trigonometric function in the expression is throwing me in a loop and need some guidance on how to evaluate this.

Thanks.

Comment: Re, as in the real part? We can use $\cos 1+i=\cos 1 \cosh 1-i \sin 1 \sinh 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos(1+i)=\cos1\cos i-\sin1\sin i\\
\cos i={e^{ii}+e^{-ii}\over2}={e^{-1}+e\over2}\\
\sin i={e^{ii}-e^{-ii} \over2i }={e-e^{-1}\over2}i$$

so

$$\Re(\cos(1+i))=\cos1\left({e^{-1}+e\over2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You should know the formulas
$$\cos i\theta = \cosh \theta$$
$$\sin i\theta = i\sinh \theta$$

Answer (score 0):

> Notice, when $a\space\wedge\space b\in\mathbb{R}$:
>
> - $$\cos\left(ae^{bi}\right)=\cos(a\cos(b))\cosh(a\sin(b))-\sin(a\cos(b))\sinh(a\sin(b))i$$

So:

- $$1+i=|1+i|e^{\arg(1+i)i}=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$$
- $$\cos(1+i)=\cos\left(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}\right)=\cos(1)\cosh(1)-\sin(1)\sinh(1)i$$

We get that:

$$\Re\left[\cos(1+i)\right]=\Re\left[\cos\left(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}\right)\right]=$$
$$\Re\left[\cos(1)\cosh(1)-\sin(1)\sinh(1)i\right]=\cos(1)\cosh(1)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$2\cos(a+ib)=e^{i(a+ib)}+e^{-i(a+ib)}=e^{-b}e^{ia}+e^be^{-ia}$$

Use Euler Identity: $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$